# Remote git repository with existing code base

Tags: git

I've got existing project on web server, which I want to start tracking using git. I did the `git init` command. and the git repository was initialized.

Then, on my local machine I initialized the git repository and run this command: `git remote add origin xxx@example.com:/home/repositoires/repo`.

The newly added remote repository is listed after running command: `git remote -v`. However, when I try to pull from the remote repository, I get error about repository not being found.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to get a remote repo locally, why not clone instead?

Comment: Does `xxx@example.com:/home/repositoires/repo` exist? The error seems to indicate that it doesn't.

Comment: If you are not using any hosting service like Gitlab, you need to run `git daemon` in the remote repository to set up a simple server.

Answer (score 1):

First verify that there is, indeed, a **empty** repository waiting for you at the example repository address. If there isn't, then you'll be unable perform the following actions.

Your webserver should have done this:

```
git init
git remote add origin xxx@example.com:/home/repositoires/repo
git add .
git commit -m"Initial Commit"
git push -u origin
```

And then your local machine should do this, into an empty directory:

```
git clone xxx@example.com:/home/repositoires/repo
```

Comment: Sidenote: Make sure your project has a `.gitignore`!